# Matlab multi cursor key doesn't work for Mac

Tags: matlab, editing

I'm currently using an M2 MacBook Pro to run MATLAB. I wanted to use the multi-cursor feature (also known as column selection) in MATLAB, but even when I press the Option key, it doesn't work. Is there anyone who has experienced similar issues or knows how to resolve this?
[text](https://kr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/edit-and-format-code.html#mw_18eef3df-221b-4b1f-951e-2cc2a8e9af23)

Comment: which version of Matlab re you running? And you are trying to select in the editor, live editor, command window, ...?

Comment: I’ve used this feature on a Mac. So it’s either you’re using it in the wrong window, you’re using the wrong key, or you’re using the wrong version of MATLAB.

Comment: From the page you linked: *”Before R2021b, column selection is available only in the Live Editor, not in the Editor.”*